# jQuery validate() function

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a credit application form. If there is a co-applicant, I want to run the same validation for the primary applicant. Currently, I have:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#cApp").validate({
        rules: { ... },
        messages: { ... }
    });

    $('#coApp').click(function() {
        var coAppVal = $('input[name=coApp]').val(); 
        if (coApp == 1) {
            $('#sec_FirstName').rules("add", {
                required:true, 
                messages: {
                    required: " <span style='color:red;'>Please enter co-applicant's first name</span>"
                }
            });     
        });
```

this works. thanks
found this link:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules
in case somebody else runs in the same problem

Comment: What are cApp and coApp? Are they submit buttons, checkboxes or something else?

Comment: cApp is the id for the form. and coApp is the id of the checkbox to add a co-applicant.

Comment: so everything works fine now?

Comment: @FALCONSEYE- you should have probably kept your original question and then posted the correct answer you derived